# Why is the heap memory in python called private?

Tags: python, memory-management, heap-memory

As the title says, why is the heap memory called private heap in Python?

P.S.: I've already searched enough over the Internet, but did not find anything that explains specifically on why is it called private?

Answer (score 0):

To paraphrase [the memory management docs](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/memory.html):

> Memory management in Python involves a private heap containing all Python objects and data structures. The management of this private heap is ensured internally by the Python memory manager. [...] It is important to understand that the management of the Python heap is performed by the interpreter itself and that the user has no control over it [...]

In other words, it is private to the interpreter and managed by the interpreter.

In a broader sense, it's also private to the process running the interpreter, and not e.g. shared memory, but that's somewhat beyond the point.

Comment: Put another way, the heap is an implementation detail of CPython, not part of the Python data model. (My favorite hypothetical example is a Python implementation that uses a SQL database to store all the objects instead of a heap.)